# How to insert each information, from a list, in the related object?

Tags: java, java-11

I have this response from some call:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": "12345678",
      "name": "Name lastName",
      "someBoolean": true
    },
    {
      "id": "987654321",
      "name": "Name2 lastName2",
      "someBoolean": false
    }
  ]
}
```

That response is inserted in class `InformationResponse`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
    public class InformationResponse  {
      private List<Information> info = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

The class `Information` has the fields:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
    public class Information  {
    
      private String id = null;
    
      private String name = null;
    
      private Boolean someBoolean = null;
    
    }
```

And I have a `context` that must contain this list of `Information` class, but inserted in the correct object.
The id was previously filled out, so I must compare the Id's that came from the response and insert them in the right object in my `context`.

My context class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
    public class MyContext {
        private Information clientOne; //id 12345678
        private Information clienteTwo; //id 987654321
    }
```

So, how can I insert the items from response inside the right object in my context ?

something like:

```
if(myContext.getClientOne().getId().equals(response.getId()) {
  // set the fields here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method to find an `Information` instance by the id may be implemented and used to populate the context:

```java
public static Optional<Information> findInfoById(List<Information> list, String infoId) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(i -> infoId.equals(i.getId()))
               .findFirst();
}
```

Assuming that `MyContext` class has an all-args constructor, the fields may be populated as :

```
List<Information> infoList = informationResponse.getInfo();

MyContext context = new MyContext(
    findInfoById(infoList, "12345678").orElse(null),
    findInfoById(infoList, "987654321").orElse(null)
);
```

or using appropriate getters/setters:

```java
MyContext context; // initialized with clientOne / clientTwo set

List<Information> infoList = informationResponse.getInfo();

findInfoById(infoList, context.getClientOne().getId()).ifPresent(context::setClientOne);
findInfoById(infoList, context.getClientTwo().getId()).ifPresent(context::setClientTwo);
```

Comment: edited the question with lombok annotations.

Comment: I provided two examples: the first is dealing with creating a new context from response, the second sets `clientXx` values in the existing context if the response contains matching id.